# Unable to get JSON Object type array

Tags: java, android, json, arrays

I have the following code

```
public static ArrayList<NameValuePair> getParticipants(String jData)throws JSONException{
    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jData);
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> partyList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    JSONArray jPartyArr = jObj.getJSONArray("participate_users"); <-- ERROR HERE

    servResponse = (int) jObj.getInt("returnCode");
    if(servResponse == 1){
        for(int i=0; i<jPartyArr.length(); i++){
            JSONObject obj = jPartyArr.getJSONObject(i);
            partyList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("account", obj.getString("account_id")));
            partyList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", obj.getString("realname")));
        }

    }
    return partyList;
}
```

And the following JSON:

```
{
    "returnCode": "1",
    "result": {
        "chat_group_id": "82",
        "participate_users": [
            {
                "account_id": "328",
                "realname": "Jessica"
            },
            {
                "account_id": "360",
                "realname": "Chloe"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

However i get the following error:

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for participate_users
```

I have a feeling that i accidentally overlooked with the JSON formatting. Can anyone please point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: `participate_users` is nested within `result`.

Comment: argh.. yeah that's why... Thanks. Been looking for this bug for 30 mins now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to go one level below.

Try this - `JSONArray jPartyArr = jObj.getJSONObject("result").getJSONArray("participate_users");`

Comment: Yup thanks. for the answer. I shall accept it later. I guess iam just tired, that i overlooked that by mistake.